# Как искать таблицы в БД через запрос PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, запрос

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли так искать, и если возможно то помогите пожалуйста

У меня в БД есть много таблиц с названиями "1_2" "1_109" "4_9" 1010_1232" "1_123" . Могу ли я найти все таблицы где встречается единица *1* Тобиж, мне необходимо послав запрос, получить ответ с названиями Таблиц таких как: "1_2" "1_109" "1_123" ... Заранее большое спасибо.

Я только недавно начал все это изучать, но вот такая нужда появилась, буду благодарен каждой помощи

Comment: `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE ...`

Comment: `SHOW TABLES FROM datatbasename LIKE tablename_pattern`

Answer (score 0):

SHOW TABLES FROM `MY_DB_NAME` LIKE '1-%';

Я увижу список:
1-2, 1-12312, 1-234, ...

Где % - любое продолжение символов